# Range mapping process name

Tags: statistics, terminology

Does the process of mapping a random range, for example, [4; 55] to [0; 1] have a name?
Maybe it's called normalization?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would call it "normalization". You could also call it "scaling" or "rescaling".

Comment: Interesting. After reading "normalization" I agree... but another thing that came to mind was "transformation" because the mapping function could be considered a transformation. Do you agree?

Comment: @Tom: Certainly it could be considered a transformation, but that's a lot more general than "normalization". "Transformation" is basically a synonym for "mapping", which occurred in the question, but the question was about a specific kind of mapping.